# How to ensure that a cookie is NOT present

Tags: rest-assured

What would be a good way in *REST Assured* to ensure that a cookie is **absent**? I checked that there are many `.cookie` and `.cookies` methods, but none support checking the absence of a cookie.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not finding anything OOTB, but this works:

```
assertThat(response.getCookie("foo"), is(nullValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Would fetching all cookies, iterating over it and asserting over that the expected cookie is not present solve your problem? Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the response to access the cookies directly. Here's a (hopefully) real world example:

```
  @Test
  public void traceNotSupported() {
    ExtractableResponse<Response> response =
        given()
            .cookie(SOME_COOKIE)
            .header(SOME_HEADER, "some-value")
        .when()
          .request(Method.TRACE)
        .then()
          .contentType(not(equalTo("message/http")))
          .statusCode(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED_405)
          .extract();

    assertFalse(response.headers().hasHeaderWithName(SOME_HEADER));
    assertFalse(response.cookies().containsKey(SOME_COOKIE));
  }
```