# How to check a cookie name is “not” present on page using Katalon Studio?

Tags: cookies, groovy, katalon-studio

I need to check that a cookie is "NOT" present on-page.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082765/how-to-ensure-that-a-cookie-is-not-present), I have tried the following on the scripted Katalon mode:

- added these to the standard import from the test case:

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.driver.DriverFactory as DriverFactory

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver as WebDriver
```

- then I wrote:

  WebUI.verifyMatch(driver.manage().getCookieNamed('foo'), is(null()))
- and then I get the following error on null pointer

> FAILED Reason:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object

Is there a way to write a check on "none" existing cookies using the script mode for Katalon Studio?

P.S:
I have tried this other approach

```
try {
    _fbp = driver.manage().getCookieNamed('_fbp').getName()
}
catch (Exception e) {
    String _fbp = new String('Something went wrong')

    System.out.println('Something went wrong')
} 

WebUI.verifyMatch('Something went wrong', _fbp, false)
```

It fails only on the verifyMatch part. It seems that 'something went wrong' does not really get stored in the variable `_fbp`.

> FAILED.
> Reason:
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: _fbp for class:

Answer (score 0):

`WebUI.verifyMatch()` is used for checking matching between [two strings](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/common-verify-match.html).

You can do that using the plain Groovy assert. Instead of

```
WebUI.verifyMatch(driver.manage().getCookieNamed('foo'), is(null()))
```

do this:

```
assert driver.manage().getCookieNamed('foo').is(null)
```